# in NuxtJS 3 I see error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')

Tags: navigation, nuxtjs3, parent-node

I use NuxtJS3, and when I navigate between pages, after some navigations I see this error
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode').

```
"@nuxtjs/supabase": "^1.1.6",
"nuxt": "^3.10.3",
```

I've updated nuxt, node version, also wrapped  with , but still see this problem,